# How to format date in javascript without any plugins?

Tags: javascript

I want to format date to have something like this:

```
6.12.2017 10:44:33
```

I want to use only js not any plugin.

I tried like this:

```
new Date(entry.duedate).toLocaleString()
```

But this is not what i want because i get date like this : 6/12/2017

Comment: Hi. Look at the option of https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: You just need to replace the back slashes with dots, also you need to use toLocaleTimeString() https://jsfiddle.net/gefmang3/